# How to get LookUp record value in apex class when its is invoked from Process Builder?

Tags: apex, process-builder

I have `QuoteLineItem` object where I have a field called `QuoteManager__c` which is look up to `User` object . I have a scenario where I have to send an email to `QuoteManager__c` from Process Builder. I have invoked apex class from PB and sending the Sobject (QuoteLineItem). In my apex class, I can get the `QuoteManager__c` but not the `QuoteManger__r.Email`

Without doing a query is it possible to get the related record email in PB?

Comment: any reason you couldn't just create an email alert for Quote Line Item and utilize the `Related User` feature of `Recipient Type`? You could call that email alert in PB. It's not clear if you need apex for something else within the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field on `QuoteLineItem` with the formula `QuoteManager__r.Email` to make that email available on `QuoteLineItem` (and thus usable in your `@invocableMethod` method in Apex)

Comment: Yeah.thats good idea but do we have any options instead of creating field

Comment: @sfdccoder It's that, or using a query.

Comment: is it possible via flow ?